# Makefile não funciona em MINGW64. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Tags: python, git, django, makefile, sublime-text-3

Estou programando em python em Django com o Sublime Text 3, usando o Git Bash MINGW64.

Criei o makefile mas quando executo recebo "bash: make: command not found"

Comment: Ele não encontrou o programa `make`, possivelmente ele não está instalado para o seu MingW

Answer (score 1):

O bash não está encontrando o make, ele pode não estar instalado ou pode não estar no seu path.

Certifique-se que ele está instalado, e caso esteja crie uma variável de ambiente e adicione-a ao path do sistema.